# Horizontal Scalable game state nodejs

Tags: node.js, state, propagation

I am in the process of creating a card game and i am currently trying to decide on the best approach for scalability. My initial thought is to be able to scale horizontally, this has lead me to implement socket.io and redis to propagate messages between instances. I am now trying to figure out how to share game state between instances take this psudo code for example

```
class Game {
    this.games = {};

    async updateGameState = () => {
        this.games[game_id] = {game: state}
        persistState()
    }

    persistState = () => {
       database.update(this.games[game_id])
    }
}
```

How should I go from storing game state in memory to propagate game state across instances, my initial thought is also Redis.

Judging by the most popular online casinos where there only ever seems to be around 10,000 clients online at a time am i simply over thinking it? should i just stick to vertically scaling if necessary?

Comment: Using redis for keeping state in a horizontally scaled environment is a good solution though you also have to think about the scale of the redis process.  We can't really offer an opinion on whether your eventual scale will need horizontal scaling or not because that would require bench testing at scale with your actual app in order to know where its limits are with a single server.  Some apps can handle 10,000 connected users on a single server, some cannot.  It all depends upon what the app is doing, how well its written and what level of server and configuration you have.

Comment: Yea ok fair enough, i guess ill build my state management with something like redis straight from the offset then i can address these issues later when i'm able to bench my app thanks

Comment: Personally, I would build in stages. I would probably design a simple little API that I could put redis behind at some point, but I'd build a Minimum Viable Product on one server, get that running, and have people using it before I actually put redis into the equation.  The shortest path to Minimum Viable Product without creating too much throw-away code can be very beneficial to understanding your real priorities as early as possible and is considered a good way to do things because it helps you find the quickest path to wherever you end up which isn't always the same as the original plan.

Comment: FYI, see [definition and reasoning behind Minimum Viable Product](https://www.agilealliance.org/glossary/mvp).

Comment: @jfriend00 thanks for the advise, day after i posted i came to this conclusion, you are right. thanks for taking the time to reply.